# 5 popups buttons are in my page. with different background and content. how it works?

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

any option to use 5 popups with different bg color and content in one single page?

I'm try to use this code http://istockphp.com/demo/popup-div-with-jquery/

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: So... do you want to remove these popups?

Comment: 5 buttons showing 5 popups.that 5 popups are in 5 different background and content. how it works?

Comment: no, i want that popups.

Comment: i need 5 popups with different bg and content.

Comment: 1 2 3 4 5 are buttons. if you click on 1 that show (red background with some content),on 2 (green bg with content) etc.

Comment: code is too long to shown.

Comment: http://istockphp.com/demo/popup-div-with-jquery/ by using this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Give the buttons a class and an id, like `<button class="popupButton" id="button1" />`
2. Hide the popups by default. By setting them in css to `display:none`.
3. create a jquery code like this:

   ```
   $('.popupButton').click(function(){

       if($(this).attr('id')=="button1")
           $('#popup1').show();
       if($(this).attr('id')=="button2")
           $('#popup2').show();
       // etc...

   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Well Hans Wassink gave already a very good hint how you can archive your goal. Are you already having some code? Maybe we can help you trying to fix your errors.

Comment: i use this code to create more that 1 popup.
http://istockphp.com/demo/popup-div-with-jquery/
but it doesn't works.

Comment: So what did you change to create more then one popup?